# How to put data into elastic search from talend etl?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, talend, elk

Trying to load the transformed output data of Talend ETL to Elastic Search of ELK.

Answer (score 0):

The below blog post describes about enabling the functionality to put the execution logs automatically to `Amazon S3 Bucket` and from there use `Lambda` to send data from `S3` to `Amazon ES domain`. As per your use-case you could tweak this functionality and populate/transfer your transformed output data of `Talend ETL` into `S3` and from there to `Amazon ES`.
[Link](https://www.talend.com/blog/2019/09/09/elk-with-talend-cloud/).